# Printing specific text from 2 spans on same line with beautifulsoup using python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am continuing my data files by pulling multiple stats based on players in a video game. I am using BeautifulSoup and am able to get to the point where the text I want is in a string, but the problem is there are two spans located so it's pulling multiple strings when I iterate with a for loop.

```
EXAMPLE TEXT FROM BEAUITFUL SOUP:
[<div class="stats-row"><span>0 kill rounds</span><span>6652</span></div>, 
<div class="stats-row"><span>1 kill rounds</span><span>4431</span></div>, 
<div class="stats-row"><span>2 kill rounds</span><span>2308</span></div>, 
<div class="stats-row"><span>3 kill rounds</span><span>861</span></div>, 
<div class="stats-row"><span>4 kill rounds</span><span>200</span></div>, 
<div class="stats-row"><span>5 kill rounds</span><span>49</span></div>]
```

My for loop is pulling both  texts.

```
for stats in all_stats:
    print(stats.text)

0 kill rounds6652
1 kill rounds4431
2 kill rounds2308
3 kill rounds861
4 kill rounds200
5 kill rounds49
```

I only want the specific numbers from the 2nd span:

```
<div class="stats-row"><span>TEXT I HATE!</span><span>TEXT I LOVE</span></div>
```

I've tried different renditions of findChildren().. find_next().. find_next_sibling().. I keep getting string errors.. and find_all() errors, did i mean to use find() instead? I've scoured for an answer but I can't find an answer specific enough to what I'm trying to do.

```
all_stats = soup.find('div',{'class':'columns'}).find('div',{'class':'stats-row'}).next_sibling('span')

TypeError: 'NavigableString' object is not callable

----------------------------------
"ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
```

I'm leaving work soon so I will be able to check answers when I get home, so I apologize if anyone is waiting for my reply.

Full code for where I am currently stuck:
https://www.codepile.net/pile/JP43EmrM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
for stats in all_stats:
    print(stats.find_all('span')[1].text)
```

Comment: Do you know how I could add these values to a list?

Comment: Create a list before entering the loop and then append (instead of print) to the list. E.g.: `some_list.append(stats.find_all('span')[1].text)`.